# How Can I change numbers inside TimeCircles.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I am using [TimeCircles.js](http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/index.html) plugin inside a Persian website. In order to change Persian numbers into English I already have a function that replaces each digit.
In this case I get what ever text that is inside number *"span"* and store it inside a variable. After converting into Persian I ***console.log*** the number, and it is converted correctly. But apparently the text inside the number *"span"* can not be overwritten.

Here's my js for getting and setting the number

```
translate();
function translate() {
    var day = $('.textDiv_Days span').text(),
        hour = $('.textDiv_Hours span').text(),
        min = $('.textDiv_Minutes span').text(),
        sec = $('.textDiv_Seconds span').text();


    day = pd(day); //pd() returns persian number
    hour = pd(hour);
    min = pd(min);
    sec = pd(sec);

    console.log(day,hour,min,sec); //Converting is successful

    $('.textDiv_Days span').text(day); // not working !!!!
    $('.textDiv_Hours span').text(hour); // not working !!!!
    $('.textDiv_Minutes span').text(min); // not working !!!!
    $('.textDiv_Seconds span').text(sec); // not working !!!!


    setTimeout(translate,500);
}
```

Am I setting numbers incorrectly or overwriting the numbers this way is not possible according to the plugin structure.
What is your suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very possible that your jQuery selector didn't choose the element. 
Try:

```
$('span.textDiv_Days').text(day);
```

Comment: to be more specific the selector could be "div.textDiv_Days span". What you are offering is selecting a span with that class name, which doesn't exist.